# How to multiply numbers in a range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the value of a number if all the digits from 1 to n where multiplied.
eg 5 = 120 ( 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 )

However the output is always zero but if I change the `*` operator to `+`, I seem to get the value of summing the array.

Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers for where I am going wrong?

```js
function multiValueMult(n) {
  

cont arr = [...Array(n).keys()].reduce.reduce((range, n) => range * n, 0;
return arr
}
```

Comment: Is this not just computing the factorial of a number?

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: `...Array(n + 1).keys()` starts with 0.

Comment: `[...Array(n + 1).keys()]` is `[0,1,2,3]` what is ZERO * something???? Hint, it is zero...

Comment: Ask the author of the code you're using. Or write your own version with a simple `for` loop

Comment: You broke the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just slice the `0` off

```js
const multiValueMult = n => [...Array(n + 1).keys()] // 0,1,2,3,4,...,n
    .slice(1)                                        // drop the leading 0
    .reduce((range, n) => range * n);


console.log(multiValueMult(5))
```

Comment: There are better ways than `.slice(1)`,  e.g. a simple `for` loop, or creating an array whose values start at `1` instead of `0`, or ...

Comment: @Andreas I quite like this way. It is short and concise as a helper function

Answer (score 0):

when you create the array with keys `[...Array(n + 1).keys()]` it produces `[0,1,2,3]`

So you do

```
1*0 and then 0*1 and then 0*2 and then 0*3
```

So you need to not have the zero....

**Using slice**

```
[...Array(n + 1).keys()].slice(-n).reduce((range, n) => range * n, 1)
```

**Better option is generate one less in the array range and add one in the reduce**

```
[...Array(n).keys()].reduce((range, n) => range * (n + 1), 1)
```

Comment: `slice(-n)` is the same as `slice(1)`